# Add numbers with duplicates values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out that each duplicates values add to particular data.
i have a data frame like this

```
Entity  Code    Date    people_vaccinated
0   Alabama NaN 2021-01-12  70861
1   Alabama NaN 2021-01-13  74792
2   Alabama NaN 2021-01-14  80480
3   Alabama NaN 2021-01-15  86956
4   Alabama NaN 2021-01-19  114319
```

i want to add particular Alabama values added and another duplicates also add in the same manner.

Comment: `pd.groupby('Entity')['people_vaccinated'].sum()`?

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Thanks its working but answer not like seems i want.

Comment: i want to add all Alabama's (people_vaccinated) and when it will give O/P then its showing something like this Entity  people_vaccinated
Alabama            6187869
Alaska             2040543
American Samoa      184742
Arizona           10569894
Arkansas           5232727